# Evo Pdf adding custom properties to PDF

Tags: evopdf

I am using Evo HTML to PDF library, and trying to find possibility to add custom properties to generated PDF (PDF meta-data - custom properties as key-value). 
Does such feature exist in any of your libraries or should I use another library for adding these custom properties to PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the [EVO HTML to PDF converter client documentation](https://www.evopdf.com/help/html_to_pdf/), I can't find a reference to the key-value custom properties either.

## Workarounds

- (Ab)use the Description property of the [Document Information class](https://www.evopdf.com/help/azure-html-to-pdf/html/P_EvoPdf_HtmlToPdfClient_Document_DocumentInformation.htm), but I'm not sure if there are (length) limitations).
- Attach a file to the PDF with [AddFileAttachment](https://www.evopdf.com/help/html_to_pdf/html/e4869024-0454-411d-bbf3-bad4cf1146fd.htm).